# How to accept admission to graduate school

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, etiquette

I have made my decision on where I want to attend grad school (for a Master's program) and I am ready to accept. My admission letter was attached in an email, and there were no instructions on how to accept (there is no online portal as far as I can tell). I am wondering what the standard protocol is since I am unable to find specific instructions on my school's website.

- Do I accept with a simple email reply back on the original thread?
- Do I need to write up a document and attach it to an email?
- What information is necessary to include in my reply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reply in the same form that was used in the acceptance. In this case, by email reply. You don't need a document beyond the email, but it would be polite to thank them.

And be sure you are clear that you accept the offer.

If it had been done by postal mail, the reply should be also by postal mail.